# Where should you import from when you create a firestore timestamp in Angular application

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

You can create an Firestore Timestamp by calling

`firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());`

My question is, should you import:

1. `import { firebase } from '@firebase/app'`
2. `import * as firebase from 'firebase'`

I think the 1 solution looks better, but in only works when I create a 'fresh' project on Stackblitz.

Answer (score 2):

I am still new to the firebase, so I could be wrong, but after I read the documentation from [Firebase App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App). App only support few services: auth, database, storage and etc. Firestore is not one of them. If you want the firestore to work well, you will need to import it.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
```

Hope it helps.